# syntax of switch statment in Unix SunOS 5.9?

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface

I have been searching for the proper Syntax to a switch statement for Unix SunOS. It seems I'm out of luck, perchance anyone can post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash there is the case statement

```
case string1 in
str1)
   commands;;
str2)
   commands;;
*)
   commands;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement in bash is called `case`. See `help case` for details.

```
case "$1" in
  -p) echo 'Hello, world!' ; exit 0 ;;
  -h|*) usage ; exit 1 ;;
esace
```